# How to test SpringBoot graceful shutdown?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, shutdown

My goal is to test spring-boot actuator call to shutdown my application.

I've written the following test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class MyAppTest {

  private static final String SHUTDOWN_URL = "/actuator/shutdown";

  @Autowired
  protected TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  protected ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;

  @Test
  @DirtiesContext(methodMode = DirtiesContext.MethodMode.AFTER_METHOD)
  void applicationShutsDown() throws URISyntaxException {
    RequestEntity<Void> request = RequestEntity.post(new URI(SHUTDOWN_URL)).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    ResponseEntity<Void> response = restTemplate.exchange(request, Void.class);

    assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isSameAs(HttpStatus.OK);

    await().atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
        .until(() -> !ctx.isActive() && !ctx.isRunning());
  }
}
```

I see that this test passes just fine. But after test execution, I'm getting the error below.

As a result, the test is marked as failed, despite the fact that all assertions are successful.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ApplicationContext loaded for [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@eda25e5 testClass = MyAppTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.mytest.MyAppTest}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=0}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4bdeaabb, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@71075444, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@5745ca0e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4d15107f, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]] is not active. This may be due to one of the following reasons: 1) the context was closed programmatically by user code; 2) the context was closed during parallel test execution either according to @DirtiesContext semantics or due to automatic eviction from the ContextCache due to a maximum cache size policy.

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.publishEvent(TestContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener.afterTestExecution(EventPublishingTestExecutionListener.java:129)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestExecution(TestContextManager.java:379)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterTestExecution(SpringExtension.java:129)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the test that is already there in spring boot actuator code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/f1ec810caf8c6f795f1119a818689d365c07ca93/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-actuator/src/test/java/smoketest/actuator/ShutdownSampleActuatorApplicationTests.java)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class SampleActuatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleActuatorApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public HealthIndicator helloHealthIndicator() {
        return () -> Health.up().withDetail("hello", "world").build();
    }

}

---

@SpringBootTest(classes = { ShutdownSampleActuatorApplicationTests.SecurityConfiguration.class,
        SampleActuatorApplication.class }, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ShutdownSampleActuatorApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void testHome() {
        ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> entity = asMapEntity(
                this.restTemplate.withBasicAuth("user", "password").getForEntity("/", Map.class));
        assertThat(entity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        Map<String, Object> body = entity.getBody();
        assertThat(body.get("message")).isEqualTo("Hello Phil");
    }

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    void testShutdown() {
        ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> entity = asMapEntity(this.restTemplate.withBasicAuth("user", "password")
                .postForEntity("/actuator/shutdown", null, Map.class));
        assertThat(entity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        assertThat(((String) entity.getBody().get("message"))).contains("Shutting down");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    static <K, V> ResponseEntity<Map<K, V>> asMapEntity(ResponseEntity<Map> entity) {
        return (ResponseEntity) entity;
    }

    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
        }

    }

}
```